# Capitalisations in Email Address

Tags: email, capitalization, capitalize, email-address

I have sent a mail to an address with a suffix of @rediffmail. But instead i wrote @Rediffmail. As you can see the 'R' is capitalized when it is not supposed to be. 
What I want to ask is that will the email still reach the recipient?
I tried testing it from gmail but it automatically changes the 'R' to 'r'.

Comment: If only there was a way to test this...

Comment: @David, that's a good point but here's another one. One sample does not a trend make. We see this in the C standard all the time. While a hundred implementations may do something the same way, that doesn't mean it's required by the standard :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain part of an email address is not meant to be case sensitive so, yes, it should work.

[RFC952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc952) was the first standard to address host names, and it states in the assumptions section:

> No distinction is made between upper and lower case.

Some of the rules of that RFC have been relaxed by later RFCs but the case insensitivity still stands.

Comment: At the very least it should reach the destination server, although I suppose they could have a rule to reject those with capitals, or a poor redirection rule that doesn't check for capitals?

Comment: Email servers don't have "redirection rules".

Answer (score 0):

Today I have found out why someone on my mailing list has not been receiving my emails.  I was dispatching my emails to n*******@hotmail.co.uk and not receiving any error messages.  However it turns out my contact's email address is actually N*******@hotmail.co.uk.  When I capitalise the first letter my emails get delivered.  Thus it appears that, on some email servers at least, the first part of the address can be case sensitive.  This is contrary to what most web sites are saying on this issue.